# Returning copied value of vector element in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have searched SO and Google for 3 hours and cannot find the resolution for what I am seeing.

I have a .cpp vector support program which provides c++ functionality to a larger c program. I already have a queue .cpp working fine, the queue pushes and pops copies of values/elements it is passed back and forth, so the exporting of functions and build is working.

A problem occurs when trying to copy and return the value of an element in a vector.

usage in .c file

```
        vector_type *temp;
        ...
        _Vector_At(VectorHandle, i, temp);
        if(temp == NULL)
            printf("null\n");
        printf("Returned %x\n", temp);
```

.cpp:

```
typedef struct
{
    std::vector<vectory_type*> q;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
} VECTOR;
 ...
int _Vector_At(VECTOR_HANDLE handle, short index, vectory_type *ptr)
{
VECTOR *q = (VECTOR *)handle;
if (NULL == q)
{
  return(-1);
}
ptr = q->q[index];
printf("Test %x\n", ptr);
return(0);
}
```

Console output is

```
Test <expected memory address>
null
Returned 0
```

I am able query values of what is pointed to by ptr only inside the accessor function. Somehow the value of ptr is being erased when it is returned from the .cpp program to the .c program. But this does not make any sense that std::queue works fine with pushing and popping values in the exact same fashion.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Identifiers that start with an underscore followed by a capital letter are [reserved to the implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/185171) so I would avoid using them.

Answer (score 2):

In the c code you are passing in the `vector_type *temp` to the function `_Vector_At`. The `_Vector_At` function is making a local copy of the pointer as `ptr` and using that to modify the value, but it is not returning that value as you want to. This is because it is a local variable and it's lifetime comes to an end at the end of the `_Vector_At` function.
To solve this you can either pass the pointer as a reference or pointer pointer:
`_Vector_At(VECTOR_HANDLE handle, short index, vectory_type* &ptr)`
or
`_Vector_At(VECTOR_HANDLE handle, short index, vectory_type** ptr)`

Comment: I'm going to blame my complete incompetence on this cold I am fighting. Thanks for the answer, makes perfect sense, dunno how I missed it. Time to call it a day.

Comment: @user3096955: If this answer works for you, you can check it as "accepted".